# intent ACTION_BATTERY_LOW broadcast firing every ten seconds. Why?

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm writing a service that must accept and react on **ACTION_BATTERY_LOW** broadcast. I'm using next code:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
...
private final BroadcastReceiver batteryBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "batteryBroadcastReceiver.onReceive()->intent="+intent.toString());
            if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW))
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW!");
        }
    };

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW);
    registerReceiver(batteryBroadcastReceiver,intentFilter);

    }

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(batteryBroadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

When battery charge level goes to low (~15%) Android sends an intent with action *ACTION_BATTERY_LOW* and then sends it again every 10 seconds which I'm receiving in MyServive. Why does it happen? What can I do or what I'm doing wrong? **Tested on real device.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The period to send [Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_LOW) is up to the OS and the manufacturer. It's informed periodically so you have updated information through time and you can make better decisions.

I don't know what do you want to accomplish but if you are getting the action repeated you can monitor also [Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY) and have a flag indicating whether the action for the low battery has been made. That flag changes its value depending on the action the broadcastReceiver receives, e.g.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
...
private final BroadcastReceiver batteryBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    private bool mBatteryLowActionHasBeenMade = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "batteryBroadcastReceiver.onReceive()->intent="+intent.toString());
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW) && !this.mBatteryLowActionHasBeenMade ) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW!");
            this.mBatteryLowActionHasBeenMade = true;
        }

        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY)) {
            this.mBatteryLowActionHasBeenMade = false;
        }
    }
};

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW);
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY);
    registerReceiver(batteryBroadcastReceiver,intentFilter);

}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(batteryBroadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

If that doesn't fit your requirements try monitoring the battery level with [Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)

Comment: Thanx for your answer. It seems that I wanted to introduce a similar solution, but in any case, thanks.